# Shortening Div Code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project [here](https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/bestinterpreters/wip/dashboard/ada/Dashboard/dashboard.004.html) that looks pretty good and does exactly what I want it to do. The codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/limemile/pen/PzqpRd). What I need to find out is if these divs that flip:

```
<div class="flip-container" id="flipcontainer">
    <div class="flipper" id="flipper">
        <div class="front" id="front">
            <img src="example.jpg"><br class="spacer" />
            <span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onClick="flipper('flipper')">&#xf013;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back" id="back">
            <img src="settings-512.png" class="settings"><br class="spacer" />
            <span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onClick="flipper('flipper')">&#xf112;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-container" id="flipcontainer">
    <div class="flipper" id="flipper2">
        <div class="front" id="front">
            <img src="example.jpg"><br class="spacer" />
            <span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onClick="flipper('flipper2')">&#xf013;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back" id="back">
            <img src="settings-512.png" class="settings"><br class="spacer" />
            <span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onClick="flipper('flipper2')">&#xf112;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-container" id="flipcontainer">
    <div class="flipper" id="flipper3">
        <div class="front" id="front">
            <img src="example.jpg"><br class="spacer" />
            <span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onClick="flipper('flipper3')">&#xf013;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back" id="back">
            <img src="settings-512.png" class="settings"><br class="spacer" />
            <span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onClick="flipper('flipper3')">&#xf112;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can be shortened in any way. It seems bulky and too "brute force method". The solution would preferably be in HTML, but JS would not be a problem. Thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend using a grid system which will help you build your app in several device screen resolution in an easy way.

Comment: Do you think you could provide a little more info? @Zeratops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any lightweight JS template engine will do for your use case. Check out this reference for examples:

https://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-templating-engines/

Basically what you do is declare a template once, and apply Javascript variables through interpolation on a template instance.
Example of what such a template could look like:

```
<div class="flip-container" id="{{ id }}">
    <div class="flipper" id="flipper2">
        <div class="front" id="front">
            <img src="{{ img }}"><br class="spacer" />
            <span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onClick="flipper('flipper2')">&#xf013;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back" id="back">
            <img src="settings-512.png" class="settings"><br class="spacer" />
            <span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onClick="flipper('flipper2')">&#xf112;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```